# IGBT and a high voltage circuit

Tags: high-voltage, driver, igbt

I have never built such a system before and have already made several mistakes. I ask for help in drawing it up correctly so that it can start working.

I intend to control the power supply to coil L1 with the IGBT transistor Q3. The power supply is a rectified AC voltage with an amplitude of 325 V.

My first (and apparently wrong) assumption is to separate the ground lines for the IC that generates the PWM signal and for the coil L. I assumed there will be a very large voltage difference at the gate of Q3, which can cause problems in the circuit to the left of the gate of the IGBT transistor.

[image: Separate grounds]

When this circuit was turned on, the resistor R3 immediately failed (or rather, its resistance increased to 30 kΩ and remains so now) and the transistor Q2 burned out.

After that, my second mistake was placing a protective diode between the IGBT gate and R3 to prevent current from flowing backwards.

[image: Protective Diode]

As a result, the resistor R3 and the transistor Q2 remained intact but the IGBT transistor Q3 began to rapidly heat up and smoke. Now I realize that it was a very erroneous decision, as a result of which Q3 burned out, but then I did not pay attention to it.

Should all the grounds be connected to each other (low-voltage and high-voltage)?

Is it better use an optocoupler between R3 and gate for galvanic isolation?

[image: Common ground]

There are probably many more points that I missed.

The last IGBT remained on hand. I would not like to burn it before finding the right solution.

This is what I found what might be a solution:

[image: TC4424]

[image: TC4424]

Comment: Some comments: 1) When PWM_30kHz = 6 V then the gate of the IGBT is pulled to 6 V - \$V_{BE}\$ = 5.3 V. That's **not enough** to switch that IGBT fully on. Look up: emitter follower because that's what Q1 is. Look at the IGBT's datasheet, figure 5, you need around 12 V. 2) Why not simply use a **gate driver IC** and duse it as the manufacturer recommends?

Comment: Replace Q2 with p-n-p transistor and put n-p-n before Q1 and Q2 as  level converter.

Comment: Q2 is capsized. Are you sure, you started to learn electronics with lethal voltages?

Comment: _"Better use an optocoupler between R3 and gate for galvanic isolation?"_ XY problem! Fix the root cause (misplaced D2) instead of introducing a new component. At 30 kHz, an optocoupler is a really bad idea for gate driving.